# How to capture next changeset in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-cli

Starting to learn Liquibase. I followed documentation, and watched tutorial videos. And I created MSSQL DB, did generateChangeLog, and changelog.xml got created. And did update on to target DB. Now I added one column, and want to capture it in next changeset. Which command should I run? Liquibase documenation says I should manually edit changelog.xml?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you manually added a column to the source database and want to generate another changelog. This would not be the recommended way of using liquibase. The recommended best practice is to add a new changeset by manually editing the changelog.xml and using [liquibase update](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/home.html#database-update-commands) to apply those changes.

Also, you can use [liquibase diff](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/diff/diff.html) or [liquibase diff-changelog](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/diff/diff-changelog.html) to generate new changesets of differences between the two databases.

We have some free training courses that will help available at [Liquibase University](HTTP://learn.liquibase.com)

Comment: please let me know if this will work. one of my requirements is that i would like my db developers to make changes in the database directly. not in xml/json/sql file. would it be advisable if i generated a source changelog once development is complete... then generated a changelog in the destination.... then diff the 2?  and using the diff, apply the change to the destination. we have multitenant environment where each client is a separate db... so the diff changelog needs to be applied many times.